# Random Color From Array

Tags: javascript, html, random, hex, background-color

I'm looking to build something with JavaScript that will pick a random value (background-color) from an array of given hex colors and apply it to a given div element.

Anyone know a good way to do this?  Nothing seems to be working for me but I'm not really a JS savvy person.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

How about this?

```
var rgb = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    rgb.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255));

myDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+ rgb.join(',') +')';
```

If you want to constrict it to known colors, you can create an array of the colors and randomly select it like so.

```
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow'];

myDiv.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VCmCD/)**

**Update** - Using the first method to apply to all `.post-content`.

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.post-content');

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
    divs[i].style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+ rgb.join(',') +')';
```

If you want to apply a random background to each `.post-content` individually, you would do this.

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.post-content');

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    var rgb = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        rgb.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255));

    divs[i].style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+ rgb.join(',') +')';
}
```

**Last Update** - using jQuery, as you mentioned.

```
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow'];

$('.post-content').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);
});
```

Comment: looks great! I've been able to get the random color but couldn't properly apply it to the style, any way to use a class with a '-' in it without getting an error?

Comment: I get a syntax error every time I add a dash into the place where you wrote 'myDiv'

Comment: That's because you can't have a variable with special characters like `-`.  What element are you trying to select?

Comment: .post-content, I would change it but it's being used in so many files I don't want to end up breaking something

Comment: Is there a way to use the other technique so I can define what colors it selects from and have it applied to each .post-content

Comment: Yes, by putting the second example in the for loop.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work, even the one you provided in your most recent edit doesn't effect the site.
I've tried it in the <head> tag, in the <body> or under </body>
Actually in the last case it crashes Firefox haha

Is the a .js library I should be importing?
Currently using jquery-1.7.1.min.js

Comment: Actually forgot to put it in the  $(document).ready(function(){}); tag haha, this seems to work fine, thanks for the help!

Comment: Ok. I've edited my answer another time for a simpler solution if you're using jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

This example returns a random item from any array, 
if you pass a non-falsey argument, it removes the item from the array.

```
Array.prototype.getRandom= function(cut){
    var i= Math.floor(Math.random()*this.length);
    if(cut && i in this){
        return this.splice(i, 1)[0];
    }
    return this[i];
}
```

//sample:

```
var colors= ['aqua', 'black', 'blue', 'fuchsia', 'gray', 'green', 
'lime', 'maroon', 'navy', 'olive', 'orange', 'purple', 'red', 
'silver', 'teal', 'white', 'yellow'];
```

alert(colors.getRandom());

Comment: Thanks for that! How could I make this chosen color the background for a given div (i.e. '.post-content')

Comment: You would use `document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor = colors.getRandom();`. In order to use a CSS property with a dash, just capitalize the next letter instead (`overflow-y` to `overflowY`, `font-size` to `fontSize`).

Answer (score 2):

```js
let hue = 0;
    let colors = []
    for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        let color = "hsl(" + hue + ",100%,50%)"      
        colors.push(color)      
        hue += 500
    }
    console.log(colors)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how well this goes performance wise, but if you're already using lodash it can be as simple as:

```
// initialising array of colours
let colours = ['tomato', 'salmon', 'plum', 'olive', 'lime', 'chocolate']

// getting a random colour
colours = _.shuffle(colours); // you can shuffle it once, or every time
let hereIsTheColour = colours.pop() // gets the last colour from the shuffled array (also removes it from the array)
```